# Android - see the arm version dynamically?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

At run time I need to determine what arm version my app is running on so I can now what ffmpeg   compiled module to include.
The only solution I found until now is to get the device model and hard-code what version of arm it corresponds to.

Is there a direct way of finding out the arm version in android?

Comment: probably reading /proc/cpuinfo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094513/android-detecting-atom-processor-at-runtime-to-select-right-ndk-compiled-library

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to find arm processor version on android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630386/how-to-find-arm-processor-version-on-android-device).

Answer (score 2):

Is NDK's [cpufeatures](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/docs/text/CPU-FEATURES.text) library is not enough?

It can query vfp version of the core, support for features like neon, idiv (integer div), ldrex/strex. Support for ldrex/strex should be from `armv6`, that can be used for distinguishing between v6 and v5. There is a direct feature for querying if core is an `ARMv7-A` profile as well.